# How to take screenshot in ios.

Tags: swift

New to swift.I want to take a screenshot of viewcontroller having all view except view 1, view 3 contain a stackview with dynamic height.I know how to take full screenshot of viewcontroller but how can i acheive this. Any help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV719.png)

Comment: try to hide those views while taking shot and then show them again

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is hiding these two views before rendering the content and make them visible after finishing the render.

```
view1.hidden = true
view3.hidden = true    
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
let ctx: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx,0,0)
UIColor.blackColor().set()
CGContextFillRect(ctx, previewRect)
view.layer.renderInContext(ctx)
let previewImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
view1.hidden = false
view3.hidden = false
```

Comment: I also need a complete screen shot of stackview which have dynamic height present in view3. How to that. It only show the height according to the viewcontroller height.For example i have a stackview which have double of the height of the viewcontroller but it show according to the vc height.

Comment: calculate it and put it here: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(SIZE, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)`